# How to get the simple generic type name?

Tags: java, generics, return

I want to get a String representation of a methods return type with type arguments but without package name, like "List".

From the class object of the return type we can get the simple name without package prefix via `method.getReturnType().getSimpleName()` but without generics type parameters. Output: `List`

It is also possible to get the generic type arguments in long form via `method.getGenericReturnType().toString()`. Output: `java.util.collections.List<java.util.String>`

But how to get a simple name with generic type arguments?

E.g: `List<String>` instead of `java.util.collections.List<java.util.String>`

Comment: you can split it by "." (dot) and read the last index.

Comment: there is a method getSimpleName() try that

Comment: +Warn: java.util.String is same as com.anees.String lexically

Comment: What's `java.util.collections`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write simple class which recursively traverse type and generate simple name on each level:

```
class TypeSimpleName {

    private final Type value;

    public TypeSimpleName(Type value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return getName(value);
    }

    private String getName(Type type) {
        if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            return getParameterizedTypeName((ParameterizedType) type);
        }
        if (type instanceof Class) {
            return getClassSimpleName(type);
        }
        // handle other types if needed

        return type.getTypeName();
    }

    private String getParameterizedTypeName(ParameterizedType type) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        builder.append(getName(type.getRawType()));
        Type[] typeArguments = type.getActualTypeArguments();
        if (typeArguments.length > 0) {
            builder.append("<");
            for (int i = 0; i < typeArguments.length; i++) {
                Type arg = typeArguments[i];
                builder.append(getName(arg));
                if (i < typeArguments.length - 1) {
                    builder.append(", ");
                }
            }
            builder.append(">");
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String getClassSimpleName(Type type) {
        return ((Class) type).getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getReturnTypeName("getList"));
        System.out.println(getReturnTypeName("getListList"));
        System.out.println(getReturnTypeName("getObj"));
        System.out.println(getReturnTypeName("getMapMap"));
    }

    private static String getReturnTypeName(String method) {
        Type returnType = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(Test.class, method).getGenericReturnType();

        return new TypeSimpleName(returnType).getName();
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return null;
    }

    public List<List<String>> getListList() {
        return null;
    }

    public Integer getObj() {
        return 1;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<Integer, BigDecimal>> getMapMap() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
List<String>
List<List<String>>
Integer
Map<String, Map<Integer, BigDecimal>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can walk over the type tree using a simple method like this:

```
  static String simpleTypeName(Type t) {
    if (t instanceof ParameterizedType) {
      ParameterizedType p = (ParameterizedType) t;
      return simpleTypeName(p.getRawType())
          + Stream.of(p.getActualTypeArguments())
              // Recurse to handle the type arguments.
              .map(YourClass::simpleTypeName)
              .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "<", ">"));
    } else if (t instanceof Class) {
      Class<?> c = (Class<?>) t;
      return c.getSimpleName();
    } else {
      // ... handle other Type subtypes.
    }
  }
```

and invoke like:

```
String typeName = simpleTypeName(yourMethod.getGenericReturnType());
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/6ubXQI)

Comment: @MohamedAneesA, but author intentionally does not want to have packages, so it should not be a problem.

Comment: @MohamedAneesA you can delete your comments here now :)